# Issue with Copying SSH Key to Container

Tags: docker

Im trying to copy my local private ssh key into a container. Using a volume mount at run time. Like so:

```
rick@LAPTOP-D5547FDI:~/workspaces/ansible$ docker run -v /c/Users/rick/.ssh/:/root/.ssh/:ro -d -t rickd3/ansible:latest
```

However, when i go into the container there are no files present (??)

```
rick@LAPTOP-D5547FDI:~/workspaces/ansible$ ls -l ~/.ssh/
total 12
-rw------- 1 rick rick 1675 Feb  3 20:37 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 rick rick  402 Feb  3 20:37 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 rick rick 2434 Feb  6 20:37 known_hosts
rick@LAPTOP-D5547FDI:~/workspaces/ansible$ whoami
rick
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to make sure, are you logged in as the root user in your container?  What does `whoami` return?  If you're not the root user, then `~/.ssh/` won't contain any keys you mounted to that directory.

Comment: yep, correct i am root.